# Get meta information from a java package from the maven central

Tags: java, rest, maven, maven-central

Is there a way of getting the meta information described in a pom.xml from maven central via rest API? I'm interested in the following fields

```
<url>
<organization>
<scm>
```

The search result exposes just a few fields. http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?wt=json&rows=20&q=fc:%22org.springframework.boot%22

Comment: You need to load the pom files and you can read the meta information...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. From where can I get those pom files? Are the accessible via maven central rest API somehow?